# How to save checkbox values to database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, ruby-on-rails-4

I need some little help. I have a Client and Assignment model. Assignment tables are already full with data. When I am creating a client I have added checkboxes with assignments to Client creation form. Checkboxes are populated with data from Assignment table. Admin can choose which assignments will add to client and save the Client and ClientAssignments. Now I was wondering how can I save ClientAssignments after admin submits the form? What should I do in controller? This is my code:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assignments, :through => :client_assignments
  has_many :client_assignments
end

class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :clients, :through => :client_assignments
  has_many :client_assignments
end

class ClientAssignment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :client
    belongs_to :assignment
end
```

ClientAssignment table has only client id and assignment id:

```
create_table "client_assignments", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "client_id"
    t.integer  "assignment_id"
  end
```

Checkboxes:

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :assignment_ids, Assignment.all, :id, :name %>
```

How can I fetch selected checkboxes in controller and create new rows in ClientAssignement table? Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19634213/rails-how-to-store-has-many-checkboxes-association-in-database

Comment: Have a google for "rails has_and_belongs_to_many" - you don't need to be doing this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Like the others commented, it looks like you need has_and_belongs_to_many association instead of has_many through. HMT should be used when you need extra fields in the relation, if not only HABTM would be sufficient. Also note that the join table should be called AssignmentsClients because of Rails naming convention: both models should be plural and order in alphabetical order. So here is what you can do:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many_and_belongs_to_many :assignments
end

class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many_and_belongs_to_many :clients
end
```

The AssignmentsClients table migration:

```
create_table :assignments_clients, id: false do |t|
    t.integer :assignment_id
    t.integer :client_id
end
```

All the rest will be taken care of by Rails.